# Sanding Down Portion of Flagstone Patio

Tags: patio, crawlspace

Good morning - I'm installing a new door to my crawl space that provides a tighter seal.  The older door left a small gap underneath the door.  The crawl space door is right off of my flagstone patio.  The problem is that the larger sized crawl space door gets caught on a slightly raised portion of a piece of flagstone, so that you aren't able to open it.

Is it safe to just sand down this small portion of the flagstone, so that the door will open cleanly?  Or will sanding down the flagstone compromise its integrity?

A picture of the current door with the flagstone patio is attached.[image]

Thank you!

Comment: How thick is the stone? You might not compromise integrity but I am willing to bet you will compromise its appearance. Can you pry it up, remove some substrate, and put it back down?

Comment: It might be easier just trim the bottom of the door. Sanding the stone is difficult, with risk to damage it. Another way is to relevel the sandstone, if it can easily lifted up.

Comment: You might consider adding a door sweep/seal to the existing door instead of replacing it. I'm not sure how much of a "seal" you're looking for, though, so this might not suffice.

Comment: The slabs look like Indian sandstone, as said above, they would look dreadful after any sanding or cutting. How about ‘rising hinges’ on the doors? Or as said, trim the bottom of the door and fit a weather strip on the inside of the doors where the bottom of the door would butt up to?

Comment: Thanks all for the comments.  You've reaffirmed my thought that sanding down the stone isn't a smart idea.  Someone I typically trust proposed the idea, but I'm glad I got your opinions first. I will go with adding some sort of trim to the bottom of the door